# In MVC/ASPX what are the difference between FormAttribute and BindAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC.
What are the difference between

```
public ActionResult MyAction([Form] MyClass myClass) {...}
```

and

```
public ActionResult MyAction([Bind(Include = "...")] MyClass myClass) {...}
```

Also, what is the default behavior of the Bind attribute? I mean, in this case

```
public ActionResult MyAction([Bind] MyClass myClass) {...}
```

the behavior is to inlcude all or exclude all?

Comment: `[Bind]` without parameters is unnecessary - all matching form values, query string values etc. are bound by default. What is `[Form]`?

Comment: System.Web.ModelBinding.FormAttribute. I think it does exactly the same as Bind without parameters but I'm not sure.

Comment: `System.Web.ModelBinding.FormAttribute` is not used by MVC

Comment: I'm reading a book, (ASP.NET MVC 5 with Bootstrap and Knockout.js, Jamie Munro, O'Reilly May 2015) and building an MVC app at a certain point the author uses FormAttribute (page 57). I don't understand why.